# Is the [NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT] a supported type for SQL Server Agent service?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, sql-server-agent, windows-server

Reading and re-reading  MSDN "[Select an Account for the SQL Server Agent Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx)".

`NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` is not listed in the "Supported Service Account Types" section.
And, if not, what is it installed with SQL Server for?
What could this possibly mean, I wonder? 
How should I better undesrstand it?

Comment: This is a service SID. I believe it would be classed as a local non-administrative user in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` is the **name** of an account, not an account **type**.

The document refers to account **types**.  As @Jon-Seigel said, it qualifies as a 'Local non-administrative user'.

Comment: There's no such account under "Local Users and Groups" (e.g. in compmgmt.msc). Isn't such account type classified as [Virtual Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(v=sql.120).aspx#VA)?

Comment: Yes, either a `Virtual Account` or a `Managed Service Account`.  Neither account type is visible in the standard `Local Users and Groups` applet.  In order to manage these accounts, you should probably use PowerShell to manage them.  Look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28WS.10%29.aspx for further info.

Comment: The document referenced in your question does not use the `Virtual Account` or `Managed Service Account` nomenclature, which is why I believe it falls into the "Local non-administrative user" category.